# ReadAllLines() local directory not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For some reason the ReadAllLines() looks in the wrong folder.

`string[] LoadLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Assets\\UserFile.txt");`

The "Assets\UserFile.txt" is located where the exe file is.
The Debugger throws a System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException with a comment:

*"Could not find a part of the path C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Assets\UserFile.txt"*

Why is it checking in the wrong folder?

Comment: Is this a ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core program?

Comment: Why are you using the `@` string prefix as well as escaping the back-slash.  You should use one or the other.  As it is, the string is `"Assets\\UserFile.txt"` with the double backslash included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Assets\UserFile.txt");
string[] lines= File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

Note: This will look in the  folder you are executing from so make sure the folder/file exists in there.

If the executing folder is your bin folder, ensure that the file property is set to "Content" and "Always copy" or "Copy when newer" within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Relative path names are resolved relative to the working directory of the process, *not* relative to the executable. So presumably your process has a working directory of `c:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

If your code needs to load assets that are effectively bundled with the application, I'd use embedded resources as a way of not having to worry about physical file paths.

Comment: Just to add that certain Framework methods can change the current working directory while the code is running, such as `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()`.